# Does backbone.localstorage work on mobile with PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, mobile, backbone.js, local-storage

I am using cordova-2.7.0 to build a single page mobile application with backbone, require.js,  jquery, etc.

I was searching for a way to treat form input as a model, and make a collection of model. In other words, I wanted to save form input to local storage until the device is online. I want to save data to local storage.

So, can I use `backbone.localstorage` to save data so that it works in all major mobile devices like iOS, Android, Windows-phone and blackberry, etc. Or what is the best way to save data before we can sync them to a server when the device is offline?

It would be nice if somebody could point me some working examples or repo in github.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can go with backbone.localStorage. But, you are not required to go with another library. You can do this using `HTML` and `javascript` or jQuery while developing a `PhoneGap` application.

`Local Storage` will work using the device cache as its persistence, and works offline very fast.

Here's an example:

In your `HTML` file:

```
<input type="text" id="abc" name="username"></input>
<input type="text" id="xyz" name="password"></input>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</input>
```

In your `javaScript` file:

```
$(document).on('ready',function() {

   jQuery('.btn').on('click',function()
  {

   var username = $("#abc").val();
   var password= $("#xyz").val();

    window.localStorage.setItem(uname, username );
    window.localStorage.setItem(pwd, password);

    var usname = window.localStorage.getItem('pwd');
 });    

});
```

This is just a simple example. You can store large amount of data into `Local Storage`. All this you can do while working offline. When you get online just get this things from the `Local Storage` and send to API endpoint.

Local storage works well with Backbone. Here's a linke for a tutorial I'd recommend.

**[Backbone tutorial](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/writing-your-first-application-using-backbone-js/)**

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: i Was just trying to save form data. Can u suggest me how to save more than 1 table row as json using backbone.

Comment: Ya.That is what i am telling you.If you want to store form data you can get data on button submit event and store in your device's localStorage.But if you want to go for backbone.I will give you one solution.I am editing my answer.

Comment: I have made little changes into the code also.You can check it.